How to include same library/bibtex citations in externally linked document with different numbering schemes?
I have a table that was moved from a main document and into a supporting information document, which is linked by externaldocument
I want the citation, for example, Su2018, to be included in both the main document and in the supporting information, but numbered differently in each.
I cite \cite{Su2018} in both documents.
I need to avoid the error

Label `Su2018' multiply defined

However, I want to keep the separate numbering for figures, tables, etc. that I have.
I have also tried \usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib} but this didn't fix anything.
I've also tried https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multibib but that seems set up for different situations.
How can I get the citations included in both documents to have document-specific numbering schemes? Or just have the supporting information use its own citation numbering?
